# Сalling PL/SQL function from select statement does not work

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function:

```
 function my_func( par1 in varchar2
                          ,par2 in varchar2 
                          ,par3 in varchar2) 
  return varchar2       
  is
  l_par1  number := TO_NUMBER(par1); 
  begin 
    
    update here....
    
    COMMIT;
    
   update here....
    COMMIT;
    
    return 'ok: ';
  Exception
    When Others Then
   
      return 'not ok: '; 
  End my_func;
```

Can somebody explain me why:

```
select my_package.my_func(par1=> to_number('456565'),
                                               par2=> 'tryrty',
                                               par3=> 'try') from dual;
```

does not work, it returns an exception,
whereas

```
begin
  -- Call the function
  :result :=  my_package.my_func(par1=> '456565',
                                               par2 => 'tryrty',
                                               par3 => 'try');
end;
```

returns the right result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As per the linked duplicate and [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm#i2062159), you cannot perform a `COMMIT` in a function that is going to be run in any SQL statement or write to the database in a function that is called from a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: In addition, this is a very poor use of a function.  The entire purpose of a function is to return a value.  Think SYSDATE or TO_CHAR.  They do not perform DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).  What you want would be proper for a PROCEDURE, but not a FUNCTION.